# Styled-Components - Style doesn't work in hover context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm having some issues trying to set a different color to the background of a button depending of an attribute.

Doing something like that is not working, for some reason doesn't set the color to the background in any of the cases.

[image]

This case it works but shows a Lint error that I want to avoid

[image]

The error that it shown is: *ESLint: Do not nest ternary expressions.(no-nested-ternary)*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: paste your code please not image

Comment: If the code is working and you don't want to change your global linting rules you can disable that rule for that line: `// eslint-disable-next-line no-nested-ternary`. I don't really see why one would work over the other though, what is the error in the first example with the if-else? You may be able to skirt that rule by nesting the second ternary more deeply, i.e. `props.orange ? palette('orange', 3) : palette(props.primary ? 'purple' : 'white', 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

it say dont nest ternary operator but so you can use `if/else` something like this:

```
if (props.orange)
  return palette('orange', 3)
else if (props.primary) {
  return palette('purple', 1)
} else {
  return palette('white', 3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your first error is likely to another eslint error where you have an unnecessary else block once your if block has a return statement (*you can see the curly braces from else block with underline error*), as [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-else-return):

to solve it remove the else block:

```
if (props.orange) {
  return palette('orange', 3)
}
return props.primary ? palette('purple', 1) : palette('white', 1)
```